# Collecting data from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, elasticsearch

I have a dictionary which has many different sessions that start and end at different datetimes. Each session bucket has multiple results and each result has a timestamp.

Every result can be an error or not not.

I want to collect the data for all sessions to answer the question: do errors occur more often at the end or at the beginning of an session.

Here is a little part of that dictionary

```
"aggregations": {
        "Sessioncount": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "1dec8193-1bf8-4ba1-ade0-332a53ca01e8",
                    "doc_count": 116,
                    "SessionTimestamps": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": [
                                    "None",
                                    "2022-11-09T12:29:18.489Z"
                                ],
                                "key_as_string": "None|2022-11-09T12:29:18.489Z",
                                "doc_count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "key": [
                                    "None",
                                    "2022-11-09T12:29:18.618Z"
                                ],
                                "key_as_string": "None|2022-11-09T12:29:18.618Z",
                                "doc_count": 1
```

This session has a lot of entries, the two we see here are  not returning an error code. There are like 50 more sessions.

Any Tips or helps are welcome.

My main issue is that I can't really think of a way of looping trough the dict and for each session get the data.

I am using Python

I can direct up to the first "buckets" but no further.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(resp["aggregations"]
                           ["Sessioncount"]["buckets"])
```

If I try to go further like this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(resp["aggregations"]
                           ["Sessioncount"]["buckets"]["SessionTimestamps"])
```

I get an error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

How would you approach answering the question: do errors appear mostly in the first half of the session or in later half for each session?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Could you give me an example on how navigate to that point in the dict and iterate trough the list?

Comment: No problem, just head to the below answer.

Answer (score 3):

The target "buckets" within the object "aggregations" is **not** a dictionary but a **list**.

#### Corrent answer for your problem

```
buckets = resp["aggregations"]["Sessioncount"]["buckets"][0]
sessionTimestamps = buckets["SessionTimestamps"]

df = pd.json_normalize(sessionTimestamps)
```

###### Why has the problem occurred?

`"aggregations": {}` is a dictionary, so is the `"Sessioncount": {}`. You can navigate through these dictionaries using the `.get('child')` function or classic `['child']` selector:

For example:

```
dictionary = { "child_1": 0, "child_2": 1 }
print(dictionary.get('child_1'), dictionary['child_2'])

=============== RESTART: main.py ===============
0 1
```

While navigating through your dictionary, you stumble upon `"buckets": [{}]`, which is a **list** that contains **dictionary** data as children.

Here is an example of list iteration:

```
list = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
print(list[0], list[1], list[2])

=============== RESTART: main.py ===============
a b c
```

We want to access dictionary `"SessionTimestamps": {}`, which is located in the first dictionary of `"buckets": [{ "SessionTimestamps": {} }]` **list**. The problem is that you have to use "indices" to access the list's children.

Hence the error `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"`

For more, you can head to **geeksforgeeks** for a neat tutorial on the [difference between List and Dictionary in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-list-and-dictionary-in-python/)

I hope that helps :)

Comment: This is a great answer. @DunKing since this got you what you were looking for, you could accept McRaZick's solution as well :D